# Flutter TextFieldForm with keyboard causes rebuilds

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an inAppBroser with an Input at the bottom when touching the textField and the KeyBoard gets active the inAppBroser gets kinda rebuilds.

I googled the issue and most of the answers are defining the `_formKey` outside the build and that what I'm doing already and the issue still!!

**The code for the Form:**

```dart
class AddCommentFormBar extends StatefulWidget {

  final Post _post;

  const AddCommentFormBar({
    Key key,
    @required Post post,
  }) : _post = post, super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddCommentFormBarState createState() => _AddCommentFormBarState();
}

class _AddCommentFormBarState extends State<AddCommentFormBar> {
  TextEditingController _commentTextCtrl;
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _commentTextCtrl = TextEditingController();
    _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _commentTextCtrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container(
          // color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 12,
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    readOnly: state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated ? true : false,
                    onTap: () {
                      if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(LoginPage.routeName);
                      }
                    },
                    maxLines: null,
                    validator: (input) {
                      if ( input.trim().isEmpty ) {
                        return 'هذا الحقل لايمكن ان يكون خالي';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: _commentTextCtrl,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      // fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 10),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      prefixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add_comment,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {

                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            print('add comment');
                          }
                          
                        },
                      ),
                      hintText: 'اكتب تعليق...',  
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                      // suffix: IconButton(icon: Icon(
                      //   Icons.add_comment,
                      //   color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                      // ), onPressed: null)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with widgets rebuilding. Why is this bothering you?

Comment: it makes the in-app browser loses frames, like a black screen then back again, I don't want that behavior

Comment: Instead of trying to reduce the number of rebuilds, you should try to pinpoint why rebuilding causes this problem. The code you gave looks alright. It's probably somewhere else.

Comment: it's normal behavior for webview, it's rebuilding the webview which causes the HTML inside to reload!! The problem with the  unnecessary rebuilding on active/dismiss keyboard

Comment: It's not a normal behavior, no. If your webview reloads on rebuild, there is a bug in the package you are using.